# Writing BLE to Cycling Control Point - Adding Resistance

Tags: dart, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have bee working with BLE for a while now, but primarily for reading and notifying characteristics.

The devices specifically are Virtual cycle trainers that support **GATTS Cycling Power Service - 0x1818 [link](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.cycling_power.xml)**

I know that it's possible to increase resistance on this trainer, but I have read the documentation on **Cycling Power Control Point -  0x2A66 [link][2]** which is the only one with Mandatory write functions, but non of the documentation seem to be make sense.

**Trainer: *Cycleops Magnus***

**Reading and writing characteristic**

```
// Reads all characteristics
var characteristics = service.characteristics;
for(BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {
    List<int> value = await device.readCharacteristic(c);
    print(value);
}

// Writes to a characteristic
await device.writeCharacteristic(c, [0x12, 0x34])
```

**Reading and writing descriptors**

```
// Reads all descriptors
var descriptors = characteristic.descriptors;
for(BluetoothDescriptor d in descriptors) {
    List<int> value = await device.readDescriptor(d);
    print(value);
}

// Writes to a descriptor
await device.writeDescriptor(d, [0x12, 0x34])
```

The closest I can see is setting the crank length, or chain weight but at this stage I am only guessing and am looking for some guidance.

**The questions is this..**

> What characteristic or descriptor should I use to adjust Virtual Power
>   trainer resistance and what is the best way to do this?

**Any coding Language is fine, I can transpose it.**

Screenshot of services available for device

[2]: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.cycling_power_control_point.xml[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the source code for the app used for the Cycleops Magnus is not available. Therefore, it seems that the only way to get the answer is to do some reverse engineering which will not be straightforward. You'd need a sniffer to see exactly the ATT packets that are being sent and then try and deduce what they are. Another solution is to use Nordic's nRF Toolbox app for which the source is available on GitHub, but you'd have to do a lot of trial and error which you mentioned you want to avoid. The only other method I can this of is to contact the Magnus support and ask for the app.

Comment: Hi @YoussifSaeed, Thanks for the comment. All your suggestions are good, but unfortunately I have already contact Saris/Cycleops twice with no response and tried Nordics tool and viewed the source code ( That doesn't support this function ). I have also spent quite a while attempting to reverse engineer, but its like a needle in a haystack without some guidance. That was the hope of this question, but it seems to specific a question. Thanks again.

Comment: do you still have access to this trainer and still working on it? You're correct that some trainers are able to be controlled via the 1818 service using the wahoo's extension to cycling power service. Would be great if you still have it and we can try to work out how to get it working. I too would like to support this trainer (specially the Hammer H1)

Comment: @myjunk I still have the trainer and the code base. It became a bit too hard so I left it for now. Happy to collaborate though.

Comment: @Yonkee Great! Firstly, you can go thru this GitHub https://github.com/codeinversion/sensors-swift-trainers/blob/93db8dd000e47233435a41ba061c23541ee18bb4/Sources/SwiftySensorsTrainers/CycleOpsService.swift  you'll see that it uses the UUID you have in your screenshot. You first need to send a ```request control``` command to it. (0x00) Only after that , you can start sending Wattage target to it. You should be able to use an app like ```BLE Hero / NRF Connect``` to send these packets to the trainer. 

Could you give it a go?

Comment: Your trainer is a cycleOps Magnus, which I think the writable UUIDis different from the one on the Hammer H1. ```(A026E005-0A7D-4AB3-97FA-F1500F9FEB8B)```. But let's see if the procedure to ```unlock/control``` the trainer works first. Since SO doesn't have a PM system, you can (if you want) email me using the details in my profile and we can work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong Bluetooth service for this. The Cycling Power Service is for collecting data from cycling power meters like this one: https://www.cyclist.co.uk/reviews/6705/long-term-review-fsa-powerbox-carbon-power-cranks

For your requirements, I believe you should be using the Fitness Machine Service (0x1826) which includes the Indoor Bike Data characteristic (0x2AD2) and most importantly for you, the Fitness Machine Control Point characteristic. Take a look at section 4.16.1 of the Fitness Machine Service specification and you'll see details of operations which the control point supports, including a reference to 4.16.2.5 Set Target Resistance Level Procedure. I think this is what you need.

Comment: Hi Martin. Thanks for taking the time to look at this issue. Unfortunately the Magnus doesn't seem to support 0x1826 service. According to the nRF connect app, the services supported are 1818, 1801

Comment: Hi Yonkee. How do you know it is possible to change the resistance over Bluetooth? Can you post your nRF Connect screenshot here or in our support system to show me the services? If those are genuinely the only two listed, it's missing one mandatory service (1800).

Comment: Hi Martin. I have added the screen shot to show the services. The reason I think resistance can be changed or Mimiced is that when I use Swift/BKool, Rouvy and others,  I can feel the resistance change when riding uphill. I figure if they can do it, it must be possible but how it is done has left me stumped.

Comment: Thanks for adding the screenshot. I think the answer is that they are using the custom service with the 128-bit UUID for resistance control. I'm certain Cycling Power does not support this functionality and that's the only other candidate service listed. Unfortunately, this means that unless the manufacturer is willing to release information to you, your only other option is to use a sniffer/protocol analyser to reverse engineer.

Comment: I have a BKool Pro 2. It too uses the Cycling Power service plus a custom service. One of the characteristics in this service can be written to, so that must be the one used to exercise control. See https://imgur.com/a/EkhgV9b

Comment: Thats must be it, It does seem odd that a vendor makes it so difficult to utilise their product. Thanks again for your help Martin, It is much appreciated.

Comment: The Fitness Machine Service and Profile is not that old, so that's probably why these products don't have it. If I can find the time, I might investigate my BKool Pro 2.

Comment: That would great if you could Martin. Im not sure i have the tools to snif and reverse engineer the service.

Comment: You can get quite cheap sniffers these days... recommended for what you're attempting to do. That said, have you emailed the manufacturers to ask for the information you need? I don't have time to fully investigate this but here's some data from a session with my BKool. I changed resistance a total of 6 times. See if you can figure out how this is represented in the various Write Without Response commands: https://imgur.com/a/GHe2FbN

Comment: I might just invest in one. I have emailed Saris/Cyclops a number of times and also raised incidents with their support center. All to no response. Thanks for the screenshot, I should be able to make it work with a bit of trail and error now.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use cycling control point(CPP) for adding resistance. CPP can only be used to copy data like wheel Revolution from old peripheral to new one or if you want to reset data on peripheral you can use cpp.

If you want to add resistance you need to check for fitness machine i am using elite and elite have Fitness Machine Control point you can write resistance and other things like inclination, elevation etc using FTCP.

Few of the vendor support fitness machine and other have given their api or source code you can use that to add resistance and other stuff like that.

Comment: I have tested a cycling Power service trainer with Zwift/Bkool and others and all are able to adjust the resistance via some mechanism. If you look at the GATT Services the only one with write functions is CPP, so functions like setChainWeight etc seem logical. API's wont help as this is a BT integration not a Web Service. As for source code, the aforementioned services are private and no open source or publicly available. Thanks for taking the time to answer, but in this case I don't believe this is the correct answer.

Comment: I have tested these apps too with multiple trainer like Tacx, Elite, Cyclops. Cyclops dont have 2A66 which is Controllable but Swift still able to add resistance. I understood your point but most of the trainer dont support for SetChainWeight, GetChainWeight I have read their whole flags list to check. In the end i guessed the trainer like Wahoo, Tacx given their source code which you can use to add resistance and other provide FTCP like elite you can use FTCP to add resistance. if you found another way let me know for future reference. You can use Bluelight app for checking services. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Indoor trainers have a few services:

1. Cycling Power Service (ANT+ or BT also have)
2. ANT+FEC (ANT only)
3. BTLE Fitness control (FTMS)
4. TACX ANT+ FEC. over Bluetooth (https://blog.lazerwalker.com/2019/02/15/bike-game-part-2.html)
5. Wahoo's Extension to the Cycling Power Service (to be able to set Target power for instance)

To Add Resistance to the trainer to #1, you need to check if it also has the #5 service as well. (this is the UUID used - `A026E005-0A7D-4AB3-97FA-F1500F9FEB8B`)

#4 is actually a protocol which Tacx came up w/ before FTMS was a standard and some trainers still use this.

Comment: I'm trying to add resistance via Wahoo's extension. I'm not finding any guidance or documentation beyond what you wrote. Can you steer me in the right direction?

Comment: @andrewlewisdev try this https://github.com/codeinversion/sensors-swift