# Setting trainer resistance using Swifty Sensors and Wahoo's cycling power service extension

Tags: swift, bluetooth

I'm using the SwiftySensors CocoaPod to connect to a Wahoo Smart Trainer. It's advertising CyclingPowerService and DeviceInformationService. I've been able to get speed and power values without issue. Wahoo apparently extended the CyclingPowerService standard to allow setting resistance via that service instead of the Fitness Machine Control service.

https://github.com/codeinversion/sensors-swift links out to another Github page dealing with that extension, but that link is broken.

My question is: how should I go about setting the trainer's resistance? Wahoo's app can do it, so the machine is equipped for it. This is the only time I need to change the trainer's settings. Otherwise, I'm just reading sent information and SwiftySensors works great.

I've referenced the following post: [Writing BLE to Cycling Control Point - Adding Resistance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55135095/writing-ble-to-cycling-control-point-adding-resistance). Someone there said using CyclingPowerService to set resistance was possible without offering any guidance. I'm not very experienced with Bluetooth, so any information would be great!

Comment: You may find https://github.com/WahooFitness/sensors-swift-trainers useful. It extends the swiftySensors library for characteristics of specific trainers.
I believe that's what the broken link is trying to link to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Jordan. That was the answer. The broken link I referenced must have been pointing to the following repo: https://github.com/WahooFitness/sensors-swift-trainers

The following instructions assume that you're already able to connect to the trainer to receive data from it, like speed and power, using the SwiftySensors CocoaPod and the CyclingPowerService. Using the repo linked above, I was able to set the resistance to the Wahoo Snap trainer. Note that after you install that new repo, before you start scanning for sensors to connect to, you need to call

```
CyclingPowerService.WahooTrainer.activate()
```

From there, you set the resistance with

```
if let wahooTrainer = cyclingSpeedService.wahooTrainer {         
   wahooTrainer.setResistanceMode(resistance: 0.5)
}
```

The resistance is set using percentages. The value for resistance will be a Float, somewhere between 0 and 1.

Comment: Is there a chance that you post the whole code including connecting to the sensor and data reading. I can't get it to work with the sample code https://github.com/codeinversion/sensors-swift (I have both pods installed)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's pretty imbedded into a project that I can't share. There was a sample project out there somewhere that I was going to share with you but I'm having trouble finding it.